# Is there a way to replace all the commas except those in quotes using sed

Tags: awk, sed

```
# Director, Movie Title, Year, Comment
Ethan Coen, No Country for Old Men, 2007, none
Ethan Coen, "O Brother, Where Art Thou?", 2000, none
```

Like in here the the commas outside the quotes have to be replaced with `|`.

`Ethan Coen| "O Brother, Where Art Thou?"| 2000| none`

i did try this command

```
sed  -e 's/,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/|/g',
```

to first match those strings, put i am getting RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid

i don't know how to convert the re, totally new to shell and regex, i would be grateful for any help

Comment: Fix the formatting.

Comment: This isn't really a job for `sed` or any other regular-expression-based tool. Use a language that has a proper CSV parsing library.

Comment: You're trying to use PCRE syntax in a tool that doesn't support PCREs, only BREs and EREs. Can your input CSV contain any `|`s in any field? Can your quoted field contain escaped quotes, e.g. `"this ""is"" embedded"` or `"this \"is\" embedded"`?

Answer (score 5):

You may try this `gnu awk` command with `FPAT` to split fields using a custom regex:

```sh
awk -v OFS='|' -v FPAT=' *"[^"]*"|[^",]+' '{$1=$1} 1' file

# Director| Movie Title| Year| Comment
Ethan Coen| No Country for Old Men| 2007| none
Ethan Coen| "O Brother, Where Art Thou?"| 2000| none
```

Comment: @user8129204: Did this answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

The *proper* way to deal with CSV is to use a *proper* csv parser.

Given:

```
$ cat file
# Director, Movie Title, Year, Comment
Ethan Coen, No Country for Old Men, 2007, none
Ethan Coen, "O Brother, Where Art Thou?", 2000, none
```

First issue, your example has a two character delimiter of `', '` vs a single comma `','`. That will throw off most csv parsers unless they support multi character delimiters. For example, [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) does not support multi character delimiters. (The place where it fails is on quoted fields since if the csv parser is looking for `,"` as the start of a quoted field, it fails with `, "`...)

The lightest weight but full featured csv parser commonly available at the command line is in ruby.

With ruby, you can do:

```
$ ruby -rcsv -ne 'puts  (CSV.parse $_, col_sep:", ").join("|")' file
# Director|Movie Title|Year|Comment
Ethan Coen|No Country for Old Men|2007|none
Ethan Coen|O Brother, Where Art Thou?|2000|none
```

If you want the replacement to also be `'| '` vs the single character delimiter of `'|'` you can do:

```
$ ruby -rcsv -ne 'puts  (CSV.parse $_, col_sep:", ").join("| ")' file
# Director| Movie Title| Year| Comment
Ethan Coen| No Country for Old Men| 2007| none
Ethan Coen| O Brother, Where Art Thou?| 2000| none
```

Note that `O Brother, Where Art Thou?` is no longer quoted since the `', '` is no longer a delimiter.

---

To even be **more proper** you would use the csv module to re-encode back into a proper [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) compliant file.

Suppose you wanted to fix the `', '` into a compliant `','` and maintain the quoted fields. Our single line of Ruby does not do that.

Instead:

```
$ ruby -rcsv -ne 'out=(CSV.parse $_, col_sep:", ").map do |row|
                     row.to_csv(:col_sep=>",")
                  end
                  puts out' file

# Director,Movie Title,Year,Comment
Ethan Coen,No Country for Old Men,2007,none
Ethan Coen,"O Brother, Where Art Thou?",2000,none
```

Or into a `'|'`:

```
$ ruby -rcsv -ne 'out=(CSV.parse $_, col_sep:", ").map do |row|
                     row.to_csv(:col_sep=>"|")
                  end
                  puts out' file
# Director|Movie Title|Year|Comment
Ethan Coen|No Country for Old Men|2007|none
Ethan Coen|O Brother, Where Art Thou?|2000|none
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/^([^"]*("[^",]*"[^"]*)*"[^",]*),/\1\n/;ta;y/,\n/|,/' file
```

Replace all `,`'s between `"`'s with `\n`'s, then translate all `,`'s for `|`s and all `\n`'s for `,`'s.

Answer (score 0):

You may find `perl` better suited to handling complex regular expressions like this, when you need to avoid matching a pattern in specific context(s):

```sh
perl -i -pe 's/"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|,/|/g' file.txt
```

Or, if you need to match across lines,

```sh
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|,/|/g' file.txt
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w3vFxc/3) and the [Bash demo](https://ideone.com/yf12x6).

Here,

- `-0777` slurps the file contents into a single string (or, it will be treated as a list of lines, each of which will be fed to the regex engine separately)
- `-i` - makes changes to the input file "inline"
- `"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|,` - the regex that matches `"`, then any zero or more chars other than `"` and then a  `"` and then skips the match and goes on searching for a match from the position where it failed, or (`|`) matches a `,`  in any other context
- `|` is the replacement
- `g` - replaces all occurrences.

If your file is UTF8, and you need to make some manipulation with Unicode text, you would need to add `-CSD -Mutf8`, say, before `-i`.